# Strongly compact vs Shelah cardinals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

Does Con(ZFC+there exists a strongly compact cardinal) imply the Con(ZFC+there exists a Shelah cardinal)?

Comment: Is there anything known that supports this, other than "this should probably be the case" we all think, due to the similarity between Shelah and Woodin, and between strong and supercompact cardinals?

Comment: Maybe the fact that the existence of strongly compact cardinals imply the failure of square  at singular cardinals above them, and the fact that to force the failure of square at singular cardinals requires some very large cardinals. But the problem is that, as far as I know, we don't have core models for Shelah cardinals (while we have them for Woodin cardinals). That's why standard arguments may not work, at least now.

Comment: So this is probably an open problem?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. But I wouldn't expect it to be intractable with current techniques. We have a relatively decent understanding of inner models near superstrong cardinals.

Comment: Although it's not relavant to anwering the question, are there any results in the style of Apter-Cummings in Identity Crises III, making the first strongly compact the first Shelah carindal and so on?